# layout_height="match_parent" don't work as intended

Tags: android, xml

I have a simple view as follows;

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:minHeight="60dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_red_dark"
        android:gravity="center">

        <TextView
            android:Text="Some text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    </LinearLayout>

</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

Even though both `LinearLayout`'s height and width is clearly set to match its parent, it matches the `CardView`'s width but wraps its content heightwise.
Why does this happen?

Answer (score 2):

*I would like to comment but I have no "enough reputation", anyway.
Have you added the dependecy 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0' in gradle file? Your code works fine for me, but, I dont know if you added the dependecies.*

Comment: I didn't have the dependency but nothing changed when I added it.

Answer (score 0):

Having

```
android:layout_height="match_parent"
```

in both `CardView` and `LinearLayout` meant that `LinearLayout`'s height is the same as `CardView`'s parent's height which was smaller than 60dp. Then setting

```
android:minHeight="60dp"
```

in `CardView` changes its height to 60dp while leaving `LinearLayout`'s height the same. I replaced these two lines in `CardView` to

```
android:layout_height="60dp"
```

and problem is solved.

I still think this is unintuitive but it looks like this is what happens.